# Formatting Array saved in database to blade view in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have a DB table which stores id, cart(array), updated_at, created_at. How can I deconstruct the array and display the items in the view as list items.

3

{"3":{"name":"iPhone","quantity":2,"price":"500.00"},"4": 
{"name":"Samsung","quantity":1,"price":"344.00"}}

2019-11-10 07:50:53

```
______________________
ProductsController
______________________
public function cartsIndex(Request $request)
{
    $carts = Cart::all();
    $carts = json_decode($carts);
    // return view('cartsIndex')->with(['carts' => $carts]);
    dd($carts);
}
```

I want the cart to be displayed as below.

- ID - 3

  - Name: Iphone

    - Quantity: 2
    - Price: 500
  - Name: Samsung

    - Quantity: 1
    - Price: 344

Comment: is `cart` a multidimensional array?? it looks like so.

Comment: It is a multidimensional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use laravel's $cast attribute in your model. It will automatically help you to convert your data to json while storing in database and will help you access them as array when you retrieve them.

```
protected $cast = [
  'cart' => 'array' // name of the column you want to store as json and retrieve as array
];
```

for reference https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting